# Dynamic Methods with Expression Trees: Simple property assignment fails

Tags: c#, lambda

Following code to do a simple property assignment `person.Name = "Joe Bloggs"` by dynamically creating a method using an Expression Tree fails with a `NullReferenceException` - it's like the `person` parameter I create isn't being passed in.

Any ideas?

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void ExpressionTest()
{
    var personParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");

    var block = Expression.Block(new[] { personParam },
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Property(personParam, "Name"), Expression.Constant("Joe Bloggs"))
        );
    /* 
        * block.DebugView in debugger shows:
        * 
        *   .Block(MyProject.MyNamepace.Person $person) {
        *       $person.Name = "Joe Bloggs"
        *   }
        *   
        */

    var method = Expression.Lambda<Action<Person>>(block, personParam).Compile();

    var person = new Person();

    method(person); // **throws** System.NullReferenceException: ... at lambda_method(Closure , Person )

    Debug.WriteLine(person.Name); // I expect this to print "Joe Bloggs"
}
```

### Update

Thanks for the great answers, I saw @decPL's first that led me to removing the `new[] { personParam }` from the `Expression.Block` call.

It all makes complete sense that a `Block` scopes variables and you need to define them first (like some languages force you to) - my problem was that I didn't need any variables but was led astray by the magic `DebugView` property that the debugger shows you into thinking that they were parameters, and the `Block` was like a function definition:

```
.Block(MyProject.MyNamepace.Person $person) {
    $person.Name = "Joe Bloggs"
}
```

... which of course it isn't. It's a *block* of code as the name suggests duh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the parameter of your method to the Expression.Block method as a variable, which it is not. If you remove it, it will work correctly:

```
var block = Expression.Block(
               Expression.Assign(
                   Expression.Property(personParam, "Name"),
                   Expression.Constant("Joe Bloggs")));
```

Of course, if that's the extent of your program, you may just as well drop the block expression.

Comment: I see! I saw the first arg of `Block(IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> variables, IEnumerable<Expression> expressions)` - and being of type `ParameterExpression` I thought "ah, parameters"

Answer (score 8):

To clarify, BlockExpression represents a sequence of expressions that are executed sequentially, and returns the value of the last expression.

The version of `Expression.Block` you are using "creates a BlockExpression that contains the given variables and expressions." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324074(v=vs.110).aspx) hence it creates code:

```
{
    Person person;
    person.Name = "Joe Bloggs";
}
```

So it clearly throws NullReferenceException.

Comment: Excellent - shame the DebugView didn't show it as clearly as that

Answer (score 4):

It works as expected if you remove the block:

```
var personParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
var method = Expression.Lambda<Action<Person>>(Expression.Assign(
                    Expression.Property(personParam, "Name"), Expression.Constant("Joe Bloggs")), personParam).Compile();
```

to fix your original code, you should remove the parameter expression passed to the block:

```
var block = Expression.Block(
                Expression.Assign(
                    propertyExpr, Expression.Constant("Joe Bloggs"))
                );
```

Comment: Cheers @Lee, I needed the Block because I was (and did eventually) going to build it up to set multiple properties.